# Converting a SVG file to a PDF or JPG with the embedded base64 CSS fonts

Tags: linux, pdf, svg, imagemagick, inkscape

I have a bunch of .svgz files I need to convert to PDF, or, if that's not possible, to JPG and then to PDF.
All these files use custom fonts that are embedded in the file, using `@font-face` base64, like this:

```xml
<svg ... >
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
      @font-face{font-family:"TZ1gbTn";src:url("data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64, ... ") format("woff");}
      @font-face{font-family:"mDizxCC";src:url("data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64, ... ") format("woff");}
      ...
    </style>
  </defs>
  ...
</svg>
```

These files render correctly with the custom fonts in firefox, however when I open them locally with Inkscape for example, the fonts are replaced with default fonts.
My goal is to use a bash script to convert them all to PDF or JPG, but none of the options I've tried (imagemagick, inkscape, rsvg, cairosvg) seem to work, they all have the same issue of reverting to a default font.
So, is there a command/program which would allow me to do this in a script? Or am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see, it seems difficult to translate the fonts to PDF. In that case I will go with the image option, however I still can't get any program to rasterize the file using the correct font. I'll look into running the browser in headless mode because at this point that seems to be the only option that would work (if it actually does).

Comment: The most compact variant would be probably scripting a headless browser. I'd recommend [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer), which can [connect to Firefox](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/examples/cross-browser.js). There is even an [example script](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/examples/pdf.js) for writing PDFs.

Comment: Okay, I finally got it to work with puppeteer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think i've found the easiest solution :

chrome --headless --print-to-pdf="ouput_path" --no-pdf-header-footer input_url